# Why is CSS style specfiied by the "initial" keyword different from the default style?

Tags: css

I am reading MDN tutorials of CSS inheritance. It says set initial to property reverts the style to the browser's style. I think the browser's style it what it displays with no CSS at all? But it is different. So zero-CSS style is not controlled by the browser?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

[image]

Comment: This is interesting! I'd guess it depends on how `colour: inherit` interacts with the user-agent styles under `a:visited`...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial says that the property is reset to the default, or _unstyled_ color, usually black. Links on the other hand do have a style in the standard stylesheet. If you want to reset the color to that standard, use `color:revert`.

Comment: @MrLister I get your idea. But here is another question: in this logic, the default styles are rarely used, because the standard styles usually fill in.

Comment: @makiXIE With colors, yes. But there are heaps of other properties where the value is normally something else than the initial one. `display` for instance has an initial value of `inline`, even though most elements have other display values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initial` value reset the style to its very initial state. the blue color of the link is not it's original style, but this style given it from the **browser user agent**. but the `initial` reset it to the original color, which it black;

[image: the styles given to <code>a</code> from the <code>browser user-agent</code>]

In the image above: The styles given to `a` from the `browser user-agent`